# Not able to re-create materialized view on prebuilt table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, materialized-views

Steps I am trying to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE sample.MV(application_mode varchar2(25));

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sample.MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT application_mode
  FROM  sample.tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0;
```

When any other user is trying to drop and re-create the MV

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW sample.MV;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sample.MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT application_mode
  FROM  sample.tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0;
```

He gets below error while re-creation:

> ORA-32334: cannot create prebuilt materialized view on a table already
>   referenced by a MV

why is so?

User got a work around  for the same which is to drop the table first
and then recreate the table, recreate the MV.

Really weird behaviour of oracle is that all the subsequent attempts of that user of dropping and re-creating MV work well with no error.

Comment: `SELECT  application_mode FROM   tbl_name WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY modes` is not a valid query, gives `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`. Fix it and retry, works for me!

Comment: That was a typo.removed group by. Still facing issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem with **ORA-32334** is that you have nested materialized views.

A possible scenario is as follows - your materialized view `MV` *is referenced by* other materialized view `MV2`

```
create table mv as 
SELECT max(application_mode) application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
  GROUP BY modes;


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT   application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;

create MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV2
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT  *
  FROM   MV
;
```

The DROP of `MV`is not a problem...

```
 DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV;
```

But re-creation gives error:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT   application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;

SQL-Fehler: ORA-32334: cannot create prebuilt materialized view on a table already referenced by a MV
```

The **key** is in *already referenced by a MV*

So let find the materialized view that is causing the problem:

```
select  name, owner, master_owner, master 
from all_snapshots where 
master ='MV';

NAME                           OWNER                          MASTER_OWNER                   MASTER                       
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
MV2                            SAMPLE                         SAMPLE                         MV
```

The MV2 must be dropped first

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV2;
```

Than the materializes view MV can be rebuilt.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT   application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;
```

and after that the MV2 must be build again.

Comment: this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

update 2: it really is connected to **some other mview which directly or indirectly uses/used this one**. (*as suggested by [@Marmite Bomber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357041/1915920), but his `all_snapshots` based query does not help*)

You can find it out with `user_dependencies` (or maybe `all_dependencies`) using something like the following query. You may have to follow some dependency graph over synonyms, views, functions etc. to find the connection.

(In my case I knew that there had been a dependency before dropping the matview with `preserve table`. So this table is still "somehow connected" to some depending "higher" matview and thus the error seems to be issued.)

```
select * from user_dependencies 
where 1=1  -- for easier comment filter usage below 
  --and referenced_owner=user  -- if only current user relevant
  --and not type in ('TRIGGER')  -- e.g. to skip some auto-gen. triggers
  and referenced_name = '<my matview>'
order by name, referenced_name
```

So a **working solution was to also drop the "higher"/depending mview(s)** (e.g. with the `preserve table` option) and recreate them (e.g. with the `prebuilt table` option so there is no rebuilt necessary).

---

Previous/old findings/workarounds:

I had the same problem where I automatically "renamed" some materialized views, which is programatically not possible (11.2).
So I created new matviews from old ones

1. deleting them, but not the table data (`preserve table`) and
2. reassociating the existing table with the new ones (`prebuilt table`).

Everything worked fine but for one matview that caused this `ORA-32334` :-(

Debugging with the following SQLs did not give a clue why the system thinks this table is still associated with some matview so I can only assume it is a bug with some kind of random behaviour:

```
select * from user_mviews

select * from user_objects
where object_name like '%<some meaningful filter criteria>%'
order by object_type, object_name
```

*My workaround: recreating the specific mview from scratch.*

Answer (score -2):

This is the expected bahaviour on [11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8021.htm#SQLRF01523)

```
select * from v$version;

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Define a table `MV` and build a materialized view on it.

```
create table mv as 
SELECT  application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT   application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;
```

Now check that both object exísts

```
select  object_type, object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'MV';

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME
------------------- -----------
TABLE               MV          
MATERIALIZED VIEW   MV
```

Now drop the materialzed view and re-check the objects

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV;

select  object_type, object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'MV';

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME
------------------- -----------
TABLE               MV
```

OK, materialized view disapeared, but table exists, why?

You may want to check documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8021.htm#SQLRF01523)

> If you drop a materialized view that was created on a prebuilt table, then the database drops the materialized view, and the prebuilt table reverts to its identity as a table.

So, the table exists and you may again build a materialized view on it.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT   application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0
;


select  object_type, object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'MV';

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME
------------------- -----------
TABLE               MV          
MATERIALIZED VIEW   MV
```

Note in your case when teh materialized view is based on prebuilt table the "PRESERVE TABLE" is default behaviour in `DROP`, so teh same effect you get with

```
 DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW  MV PRESERVE TABLE;

select  object_type, object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'MV';

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME
------------------- -----------
TABLE               MV
```

The table exist after the DROP materialize view.

Please check this simple scenario to see if it works. Check also your Oracle version - `PRESERVE TABLE`was introduced in 10g.

Comment: I posted seconds answer that address your problem. Ignore this one.

Comment: Solution works for me...Needed to change my create table ddl like below :

create table mv as 
SELECT  application_mode
  FROM   tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0; 
Do you have some reason why a table ddl like this is working but 
create table mv(application_mode varchar2(25));